# Listview item button triggering other listview items on scroll with custom CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

Perhaps i'm confused about the difference between BindView and getView, but both of them cause the same problem. I have a button on every listview item that when pressed is supposed to show  an ImageView beneath it when pressed.

Ive been trying to figure this out for almost a week now, and what ive come to learn is that it has something to do with Recycling views upon scrolling and that getView was supposed to remedy that. However it made it worse in that not only was it still displaying the image on items beneath it, but it was also displaying the wrong image on the one i pressed.

Im totally lost here. =(

**This is my Cursor Adapter:**

```
public class ItemAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private Context mContext;
    ListView listView;
    Bitmap myBitmap;
    ImageView myImage;
    Cursor cursor;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(final View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

        final DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(mContext);
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listViewFromDB);

        final String description =   c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.DBHelper.DESCRIPTION));

        final String detail = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.DBHelper.DETAIL));
        final String importance = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.DBHelper.IMPORTANCE));
        final String id = c.getString((c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.DBHelper.UID)));

        final ImageButton trash = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.trash);
        final ImageButton edit = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.editButton);
        ImageButton expandButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.expand);
        final ImageView drawnImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.drawnImage);
        final TextView idFlag = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.idFlag);
        final File imgFile = new File("/data/data/com.eboodnero.memoir/files/" + id + ".png");

        expandButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (trash.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE && id == idFlag.getText().toString()) {
                    trash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (imgFile.exists()) {
                        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

                        myImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.drawnImage);
                        drawnImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                        myImage.setMaxWidth(50);
                        myImage.setMaxHeight(50);
                    }
                } else if (trash.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    drawnImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    trash.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    edit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
            }
        });



        TextView descriptionText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);

        Typeface helveticaLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/HelveticaNeue-Light.ttf");


        descriptionText.setTypeface(helveticaLight);


        if (descriptionText != null) {
            descriptionText.setText(description);
        }


        TextView detailText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.detail);
        detailText.setTypeface(helveticaLight);
        detailText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#a5a5a5"));


        if (detailText != null) {
            detailText.setText(detail);
        }




        final TextView idFlagText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.idFlag);
        if (idFlagText != null) {
            idFlagText.setText(id);
        }


        trash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                AlertDialog.Builder deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                deleteDialog.setTitle("Delete Memoir");
                deleteDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this Memoir?");
                deleteDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        drawnImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        trash.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        edit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        dbAdapter.remove(Long.parseLong(id));
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        cursor = dbAdapter.getAllRows();
                        changeCursor(cursor);
                    }
                });
                deleteDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                deleteDialog.show();
            }
        });

        edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AddItem.class);
                intent.putExtra("Description", description);
                intent.putExtra("Detail", detail);
                intent.putExtra("ImportanceLevel", importance);
                intent.putExtra("Id", id);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```